# Why is my furnace making grinding noises after thermostat replacement?

Tags: thermostat, furnace

Replaced Lux (LTX9600) with Emerson Sensi thermostat.

New Sensi thermostat will control heat but have unexpected behaviors like:

- when thermostat turn on and off heat there is a momentary grinding noise at the beginning and end.
- unable to configure WiFi without heat turning on with constant grinding noise
- When power to furnace is turned on the gas burner will turn on for 2-3 secs before shutting off. Thermostat will be set to no heat or room temp below set temp so burner is not suppose to turn on at all.

Previous thermostat do not have WiFi and did not exhibit the above weird behavior

Wiring from transformer to thermostat:
Transformer - thermostat (wire)
Y - W/E (red)
W - RH (white)
C - C (cyan)

Previously with Lux thermostat there was no common connected.

Tried swapping the RH and W/E but thermostat will not turn on furnace.

Opened ticket with sensi in case the thermostat is faulty.

Furnace is Weil McLain EG - gas steam.

https://www.weil-mclain.com/products/residential-boilers/gas/steam

https://www.luxproducts.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/tx9600ts_manual_en.pdf

https://www.luxproducts.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/tx9600ts_manual_en.pdf

Also including pic of transformer. Wiring to thermostat is the center brown wire.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What wires (color to color) were connected with the Lux?

Comment: Same as the sensi but without the common. W/E (red wire) W - RH (white wire).

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by adding a separate 24v transformer.
Rh and W connects to furnace. Rc and C to separate 24v transformer. Removed jumper between Rh and Rc.

Looks like the furnace didn’t really have a working common or thermostat was unable to draw power from Rh without turning on the furnace.

Comment: You did a fine job by coming back to answer your own question. Please click the check-mark so others know that this has a known, working resolution.